# Prove that $g\left(2n \right)=0$ for every integer $n$

Tags: calculus

I know this question has been asked here before, but I am only posting it because I still have not yet figured it out. Given an odd function $f$, defined everywhere, periodic with period $2$ and integrable on every integral, let 
$$g(x)=\int_{0}^{x} f(t)\;dt$$

prove that $g(2n)=0$ for every integer $n$.

A solution I found was as follows:

$$g(2n)=\int_{0}^{1} f +\int_{1}^{2n-1}f+\int_{2n-1}^{2n} f=\int_{0}^{1} f +0+\int_{-1}^{0} f$$
there are other steps, but what I don't understand why is the term $\displaystyle\int_{1}^{2n-1} f=0$? If I could only understand this I can proceed with the solution.

My other question is regarding a different solution I found, where,
$$g(2n)=\int_{0}^{2n} f =\int_{-2n}^{0} f(t+2n) =-\int_{0}^{2n} f =0$$
how does $-\int_{0}^{2n} f $ equal $0$? I would really appreciate if someone can help me with this.. or even propose a different approach for solving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the part where you have $$g(2n)=\int_0^{2n} f(t)\,dt=\int_{-2n}^0f(t+2n)\,dt=-\int_0^{2n} f(t)\,dt=-g(2n)$$ we just need to solve for $g(2n)$. That is, disregarding everything in the middle and focusing on the first and last equality, we have $g(2n)=-g(2n)$, which gives $2g(2n)=0$. Upon dividing by $2$, we get $g(2n)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

> ... but what I don't understand why is the term $\int_1^{2n-1} f = 0$? If I could only understand this I can proceed with the solution.

Looks like induction to me. That's an interval of length $2(n-1)$, so the integral is zero by the (not stated here) induction hypothesis.